# remote python and django console doesn't work after update to 3.1

Tags: python, django, console, pycharm

After update pycharm 3.0.2 to 3.1 I have problems with  python and django console, but remote interpreter is working.

[image: remote interpreter]

Of couse I can use ssh, but I like pycharm python and django console.

```
ssh://root@178.63.20.205:22/usr/bin/python -u /root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 0 0
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend(['/data/python/estate-kharkov.ci.ua', '/root/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm', '/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev'])
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
import django_manage_shell; django_manage_shell.run("E:/ci")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_console_utils.py", line 209, in addExec
    self.finishExec()
  File "/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_console_utils.py", line 352, in finishExec
    return server.NotifyFinished()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
Fault: <Fault 0: 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_console_utils.py", line 209, in addExec
    self.finishExec()
  File "/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_console_utils.py", line 352, in finishExec
    return server.NotifyFinished()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
Fault: <Fault 0: 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_console_utils.py", line 209, in addExec
    self.finishExec()
  File "/root/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydev_console_utils.py", line 352, in finishExec
    return server.NotifyFinished()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
Fault: <Fault 0: 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 0'>
```

Comment: Do you think, just for the sake of niceness, you could change your screenshot to a jpg and then insert it into your post? Would rather not do it myself.

Comment: I tried to save img, but "You need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Comment: Ah I forgot about the rep requirement. I'll take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is trouble with skeletons, after update Pycharm have some mistake.

**Recreate Pycharm remote interpreter**!!!

After create remote interpreter, skeletons will be updated automatically.